# a Slash adds to the string after cotation - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

For inserting strings into database, I apply this function on the string:

```
$string = strip_tags($string);
$string = htmlspecialchars($string);
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string); // removing multiple spaces :-)
$string = preg_replace('/(?:\s\s+|\n|\t)/', ' ', $string);
$string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
```

On my localhost while I test the app, I enter: `Life's Interesting`

and the exact string saves into db (Life's Interesting), then I uploaded my app on the real server, when I enter the same string, it saves: `Life\'s Interesting` in database!

Why is this happening *on just the server and not on my local host*? I'm using Wamp on my localhost. what configuration I need to change on the server so it saves right in db?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `magic_quotes` enabled on real server ?

Comment: @GBD Yes, should I disable it?

Comment: `Magic Quotes is a process that automagically escapes incoming data to the PHP script. It's preferred to code with magic quotes off and to instead escape the data at runtime, as needed.`

Comment: `Warning
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.`

Comment: So the answer is yes, you should disable magic_quotes.

Comment: it's also worth pointing out that the `mysql_xxx()` functions that you're using are also obsolete and in the process of being deprecated, so they're not recommended for use either. Ideally you should switch to using the equivalent `mysqli_xxx()` functions, or the PDO library for your database access. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `magic_quotes_gpc`

```
var_dump(magic_quotes_gpc())
```

var_dump magic quotes gpc in your both server. Your real server I think magic quotes is enabled by default.

> Magic Quotes is a process that automagically escapes incoming data to
>   the PHP script. It's preferred to code with magic quotes off and to
>   instead escape the data at runtime, as needed.

More to read [PHP Manual - Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

Comment: This should be as comment. not sure this is the problem

Comment: @GBD Mentioning magic_quotes in the answer is fine, it's quite a safe bet. The answer might be a bit more informative though.